# Draw thousands of primitives with one draw call

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to render 100,000+ number of cubes (made of 36 vertices, using indexed geometry in the same VAO) with one draw call, is this possible?

All the geometry data (vertice data) is the same, since they are all cubes. The projection and camera view is also the same and passed to the vertex shader as uniforms.

---

**Render.cpp**

```
for (auto chunk : world->chunks) {
    for (auto cube : chunk.blocks) {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textures[cube.texture]);

        // Model - transform_z * transform_y * transform_x * transform_translation * transform_scaling
        model = Mat4<GLfloat>();
        model = model.translate(cube.position);
        model = model.scale(cube.scale);
        model = model * transformation_matrix_x(cube.theta_x);
        model = model * transformation_matrix_y(cube.theta_y);
        model = model * transformation_matrix_z(cube.theta_z);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(gl_model, 1, GL_TRUE, model.data());
        // One draw call per cube is not scalable
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, cube.indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }
    // A draw call like this would be nice since they share so much data.
    // glDrawLotsOfElements(GL_TRIANGLES, cube.indices.size() * numCubes, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}
```

**Vertex shader**

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 position;
in vec4 vColor;

out vec4 fColor;
out vec3 fTexcoord;

// Model
uniform mat4 model;

// View or a.k.a camera matrix
uniform mat4 camera_view;

// Projection 
uniform mat4 projection;

void main() {
  gl_Position = projection * camera_view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);
  fColor = vColor;
  fTexcoord = normalize(position);
}
```

The number of cubes are dynamic, if that matters.

Comment: See https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawElementsInstanced.xhtml
It's called instanced rendering, which takes one set of geometry and draws it multiple times.

Comment: Given that the only thing different between the cubes are the model matrix, how could I go about setting it up so that each set of 36 vertices (a cube) would be setup with one model matrix and so on?

Comment: Are the matrices changing at each  frame or are you just setting them at initialization? If it's just for initialization, you can precompute all the position of the vertices and do your one call

Comment: in the vertex shader you can see which instance you're working with by accessing gl_InstanceID. You can use the ID as an index for an array, which stores your matrices.

Comment: @wasthishelpful: Yes, each cube has its own transformation matrix. They will not be changing and it would work do precompute everything. But I would like to keep that option open if possible.

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht: I thought using gl_InstanceID was considered bad practice..

Comment: not that I know of. How else would you find out which transformation matrix to use for each instance?

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht: Tbh, no idea. My first idea was to use another vertex attribute for the matrix and then have some kind of mechanism so that it feeds the vertex shader a new matrice for every 36th vertix.. :/

Comment: That's what instanced rendering is doing, it allows you to have a vertex attribute for the matrices, and advance the value per instance. See `glVertexAttribDivisor()`.

Comment: Note that if you have an instanced attribute you may just not need to also use `gl_InstanceID`. On the other hand you might find more convenient or efficient to store the matrices in some other kind of way (SSBO?), in which case you'll indeed need an index => `gl_InstanceID`.

Comment: @peppe you can even use a texture buffer to store the matrices.

Comment: I made it work with instanced rendering. The whole deal with the matrices was solved by passing them as vertex attributes to the shader. I am still having some problems with the matrices itself, some bug somewhere.. hehe. 

Thank you all for the discussion btw!

Answer (score 1):

I used instanced rendering a while ago when rendering particles, so we'll see if this can point you in the right direction.

Before your game loop you will call a function where you render your scene. In the function you can setup the model matrices like this, so you can have each cube at a different position in the world:

```
//matrices for the cubes
//set amount by the number of cubes you want to draw
glm::mat4* modelMatrices;
modelMatrices = new glm::mat4[amount];
```

You will then enter a loop where you will give each cube a different position

```
for (GLuint i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{    //use a function like rand() to get the x,y,z values different
     glm::mat4 model;
     model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(x, y, z));
     modelMatrices[i] = model;
}
```

Now it looks a bit different when filling the buffers, because you have to send the model matrices (mat4) as an attribute to the GPU side, so you will need 4 vertex attribute pointers for that, and also don't forget

```
        glVertexAttribDivisor(1, 1);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(3, 1);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(4, 1);
```

and at last

```
glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_POINTS, 0, 1, amount); //replace to specify for a cube
```

Then you will have to use   `glDrawArraysInstanced` one more time when you actually render the cubes.

On the GPU side you only have to replace the usual model matrix with the one you sent before.